# Cardinality of symmetric group $S_X$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, symmetric-groups

**Question**: How can I get the cardinality of symmetric group $S_X$?

I have found similar [posts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27785/cardinality-of-the-permutations-of-an-infinite-set) but they do not seam to match for me because there the advice is given to calculate the cardinality like $k^k$.

The symmetric group I am talking about is defined as:

$S_X:= Map(X, X)^X$

**Example**:

$S_0=\{id_{\emptyset}\}=\{()\}$

$S_1=\{id_1\}= \{ \left(
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1\\
      1
    \end{array}
\right) \}$

$S_2=\{id_{1,2}\}= \{ \left(
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1 & 2\\
      2 & 1
    \end{array}
\right) , 
\left(
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      2 & 1\\
      1 & 2
    \end{array}
\right)
\}$

$S_3=\{id_{1,2,3}\}= \{ \left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1 & 2 & 3\\
      1 & 2 & 3
    \end{array}
\right) , 
\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1 & 2 & 3\\
      2 & 1 & 3
    \end{array}
\right),
\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1 & 2 & 3\\
      3 & 2 & 1
    \end{array}
\right),
\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1 & 2 & 3\\
      1 & 3 & 2
    \end{array}
\right),
\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1 & 2 & 3\\
      2 & 3 & 1
    \end{array}
\right),
\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1 & 2 & 3\\
      3 & 1 & 1
    \end{array}
\right)
\}$

Comment: What is meant by the bar between the second and third columns in $S_3$?

Comment: @Johanna $S_X$ is the set of *bijective* functions $X\to X$. Thus, that question and this one are fairly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second row in any element of $S_n$ is a permutation of the set $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}$, of which there are $n!$.

One way you could go about finding this out yourself is to compute the number of elements in $S_n$ for small $n$ (e.g. 1, 2, 3, ... which you have done already) and then putting them into the OEIS.

The reason the answer of $k^k$ does not work here is because the answer you linked is for infinite sets, where $n!$ (or in this case $k!$) would involve an infinite product, where $k$ of the factors are of size $k$ because $k$ is infinite (This is not a rigorous demonstration of $k^k$, but it is designed to give some intuition on why this would be the case if you are familiar with the notion of cardinality.).